# SQLite Current Timestamp with Milliseconds?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am storing a timestamp field in a SQLite3 column as `TIMESTAMP DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and I was wondering if there was any way for it to include milliseconds in the timestamp as well?

Comment: TIMESTAMP is number of seconds that passed since 1st Jan 1970 so guess you will need another field for miliseconds

Comment: POSIX time is defined as elapsed milliseconds since midnight 01-Jan-1970 UTC.  I would say that using milliseconds as a timestamp is ok as long as you're sure it's POSIX time (i.e. in UTC).  Otherwise, the use of milliseconds for local timestamps is very unusual and you should use other numeric temporal formats instead.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670064/how-do-i-get-posix-time-utc-from-a-serial-value-local-date-time-with-the-java

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, use `(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW'))` so that your column definition become:

```
TIMESTAMP DATETIME DEFAULT(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW'))
```

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event
(when_ts DATETIME DEFAULT(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW')));
```

Comment: With Oracle background the `%f` looks weird by itself, it's the same as Oracle's `TO_DATE(... SS.FFF')`

Comment: `...%H:%M:%f` that's weird, why isn't it `...%H:%M:%S.%f` for seconds, and milliseconds? the `f` indicates seconds is a double truncated to 6 decimal places, rather than an int? ok

Comment: From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html, `%f fractional seconds: SS.SSS`

Answer (score 31):

To get number of milliseconds since epoch you can use `julianday()` with some additional calculations:

```
-- Julian time to Epoch MS     
SELECT CAST((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000 AS INTEGER);
```

Comment: Add ROUND to get more accurate thousandths: CAST(ROUND((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000) As INTEGER)

Answer (score 14):

The following method doesn't require any multiplies or divides and should always produce the correct result, as multiple calls to get 'now' in a single query should always return the same result:

```
SELECT strftime('%s','now') || substr(strftime('%f','now'),4);
```

The generates the number of seconds and concatenates it to the milliseconds part from the current second+millisecond.

Comment: Can it produce a wrong result when the two `strftime` calls happen with a tiny delay and belong to different seconds?

Comment: @algrid A query is declarative, so the actual way the query is done is not specified; so in practice (in SQLite) it's not actually making multiple calls at different times.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a query that will generate a timestamp as a string with milliseconds:

```
 select strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f", "now");
```

If you're really bent on using a numeric representation, you could use:

```
select julianday("now");
```

Comment: fyi, julianday() is not natively comparable with anything based on epoch time, whether seconds or milliseconds. You'll have to convert everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer only gives you UTC. If you need a local time instead of UTC, use this:

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now', 'localtime')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another epoch ms method

```
SELECT unixepoch('subsecond') * 1000;
1703231951563.0
```

The value is a `real`, but in an `integer` column the value will be cast.

```
CREATE TABLE "items" (
  "created_at" integer default(unixepoch('subsecond') * 1000) not null
);
```

As in `cast(x as int)`

```
SELECT cast(unixepoch('subsecond') * 1000 as int);
1703231955581
```